# Is my wordpress blogging site is safe if i am using AWS hosting?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

I am using AWS hosting for hosting my WordPress  blogging site. So is it safe for me to not to worry about any security stuff as I am using Amazon hosting. Cause I heard  someone saying that if you host your site on AWS, there are more than thousands of  security experts hired by amazon for making our site secure on the web.

I am asking this question because previously i used another website hosted on SiteGround and it got hacked and there were some malwares on my site.

I just mean that do i need to do something for security of my site on AWS?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a website for programming-specific questions so this question is off topic. Please see  [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For questions that are not coding related, try asking on the relevant site from the of [other StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) such as SuperUser. However first check their help section to see if it it on topic for that site.

Comment: That said, no matter how secure your hosting, don’t forget your *Wordpress security is just as important*! From what I have seen, websites are much more likely to get hacked through weak WP security (especially vulnerable plugins) than through the hosting. WP can have security vulnerabilities if it is not maintained properly or uses low quality plugins.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: **Yes, you have to worry.**

AWS uses what they call a **Shared Responsability Model**. AWS is responsible of the security of the cloud, you are responsible of the security using the cloud.

If you take an EC2 instance and a RDS, you have a lot of security features:

- Stateful firewall (Security Group)
- Stateless firewall (NACL)
- IAM for AWS interactions
- Encrypted volumes by default
- Super hardened OS for you DB on RDS
- ...

All of these features are monitored, hardened and updated by AWS. There is thousands of them, even some that you don't see (like the fact they build their own encryption/decryption hardware modules).

But AWS doesn't provide customers' software security insurance... If you install a corrupted software on your EC2 instance, the app security cannot be assured by anyone. If you open all the ports, put a dumb password for root access to your EC2, and get hacked, AWS cannot be responsible too.

So basically, **YES**, you have to do something yourself, but this is the case everywhere.